# SQL Trim after first space

Tags: t-sql

I need to Trim everything after the first space in a string.

Example:  Asprin Oral

I just need Asprin.

Comment: Pleeease try something and then ask. `Gimme teh codez` questions are frowned upon.

Comment: I'd use split.   string name = "Asprin Oral";
string FirstName = name.Split(new char[] { " " })[0];

Answer (score 8):

In TSQL:

```
declare @test varchar(30)
select @test = 'Asprin Oral'

select substring(@test, 1, charindex(' ', @test + ' ')-1)
```

or like @GilM stated:

```
declare @test varchar(30)
select @test = 'Asprin Oral'

select LEFT(@test, CHARINDEX(' ', @test+' ')-1)
```

Comment: This fails if there's no space.  Also I'd prefer LEFT over SUBSTRING(,1,).  A simple fix is to append your own space within CHARINDEX. Like: LEFT(@test, CHARINDEX(' ', @test+' ')-1)

Comment: @GilM Edited to fix and to put the `LEFT`part.

Answer (score -1):

You could do a `String.Split(' ')` on spaces and take the `[0]` position of the result.

[String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: OP wanted TSQL method not .NET!